Установка курсора на веб странице HTML c помощью VBA
Собственно сам subj:Установка курсора на веб странице HTML c помощью VBA.
Мне надо с помощью VBA уствновить курсор в определенное место страницы HTML. Код страницы мне доступен. Я могу находить соответствующие элементы, например, классы. Заранее спасибо.

Вы можете из vba ввполнить javaScript код в браузере? Нсли сможете, то надо выбрать нужный элемент и выполнить метод .focus()

К сожалению, не могу. Этим методом у меня получалось пользоваться, если известен идентификатор элемента. К сожалению, н странице они отсутствуют. попытки искусственно присвоить идентификатор не проходят. С классами фокус не проходит.
